# Odoo13-CE: Error message: Table 'crm_lead': unable to set NOT NULL on column 'partner_id'

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, odoo-13, notnull

When I update the modules I get this error message:
Table 'crm_lead': unable to set NOT NULL on column 'partner_id'

What should I do to prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There probably has changed something on the field `partner_id` on model `crm.lead` regarding `required` parameter. But you already have some data in database without fulfilling the `NOT NULL` constraint resulting from that change.

So you either try to fix the database table `crm_lead` by setting all `partner_id`s or you remove the `required=True` on that field.

IIRC there is no `required` or `NOT NULL` on `crm.lead`'s `partner_id` field in Odoo vanilla/default code. So you probably have custom modules changing that.

The "Error" itself is only a warning. In the end Odoo can't set that constraint in database, but will work anyway.